# Is it valid to use proof of closure under vector addition to prove scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have a set U that I am trying to prove is a subspace of V. I have already proven closure under vector addition, so I am wondering if it is valid to use that to prove scalar multiplication.

ie: Since we have proved closure under vector addition, we know for vector x and vector y that exist in U, x + y also exist in U. We can prove for scalar cx exists in U by showing cx is the sum of x + x as many times as c.

Example, for c=3, cx = 3x = x + x + x, so since we've proved vector addition to be closed, scalar multiplication is also closed.

Comment: How do you add $x$ to itself $\pi$ times?

Comment: This only works for integers, not over field of reals or complex numbers